# increase disk size of vmware machine

Tags: vmware

I'm using 13.04 as my host os and installed vmplayer and created a guest windows 7 machine. Being the idiot that I am, I only allocated 60GB and discovered I need more space for my windows 7.

When I go to virtual machine settings to increase the disk space, the utilities button is greyed out.

I've surfed some forums but I couldn't find anyone with the same scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if VMware Player command line tools provide the ability to increase the size of a VMDK image.

But if you have VirtualBox installed on the box, you can convert the VMDK to VDI, use `VBoxManage` to increase its size and convert it back to VMDK as a workaround.

```sh
VBoxManage clonehd in.vmdk out.vdi --format VDI
VBoxManage modifyhd clone.vdi --resize 102400 # resize the capacity to 100GB
VBoxManage clonehd clone.vdi new.vmdk --format vmdk
```

In VMWare GUI, attach the newly resized HDD. Boot (I recommend using Ubuntu Live or System Rescue CD) and grow the file system (note resize only change the capacity of the HDD not the file system) like `resize2fs -p -F DEVICE` for ext{3,4}.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You should shutdown the virtual machine before changing the values. Once you shutdown the virtual machine, it will allow you to use the utilities.